# Kafka AdminClient listTopics: is there a way to ignore kstreams topics?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm doing the following:

```
    var listTopicOptions = ListTopicsOptions().listInternal(false)
    var topicsInKafka = adminClient().listTopics(listTopicOptions).names().get()
```

But I'm still getting topic names likes xxx-kstreams-yyyy-changelog or xxx.internal.self.yyy

Comment: Currently there are only two internal topics defined: __consumer_offsets and __transaction_state while others will not be deemed as internal ones.

Comment: "Internal topic" is an overload term. As explained by @amethystic, there are two broker internal topic -- and the AdminClient API refers to those. Kafka Streams uses the term "internal topics", too, to refer to topics that Kafka Streams creates and configures -- however, those are regular topics from a broker point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't avoid those topic names by setting `listInternal(false)`. As mentioned, it will exclude kafka `_consumer_offsets` and `_transaction_state` topics.

If you don't want to see the kafka stream application generated changelog/repartition topics, you can define a regex in your code which can exclude all the topics matching and give you only user topics.